# Google Map search integration with Drupal

Tags: drupal, maps

I want to develop similar functionality as shown in the link, I want to integrate similar functionality in my Drupal 7 website

http://www.spokeo.com/search?q=John+Smite&sns10=t51

Please tell me the solutions for this functionality with drupal 7.

Thanks & Regards
Dsingh

Answer (score 0):

You could try powering this through Views? The Gmap module (https://drupal.org/project/gmap) will give you a View Display which generates maps. You will need to specify a location field that the map uses the generate it's markers.(https://drupal.org/project/location). In order to recreate the search you could use some exposed filters on fields such as "title", "location", etc.